# Postgres Query running slow, using pgcrypto extension in postgres sql

Tags: postgresql, django-models, indexing, encryption-symmetric, pgcrypto

I am facing issue while using the django-pgcrypto-fields. Model has charsymmetricfield and emailsymmetricfield.

using pgcrypto externsion in postgres sql, following is the output for below queries

Query 1:

```
explain analyze (select * from table_name);
```

above query taking time around 900 ms

but when i am using query with 'pgp_sym_decrypt' it taking longer time around 54 sec, that is too high

Encrypted column is indexed

```
explain analyze (select
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."sender_contact_person_name",
    'encryption_key')::text,
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."sender_contact_person_email", 'encryption_key')::text,
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."sender_contact_person_contact_no",
    'encryption_key')::text,
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."recipient_contact_person_name",
    'encryption_key')::text,
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."recipient_contact_person_email",
    'encryption_key')::text,
    pgp_sym_decrypt("table_name"."recipient_contact_person_contact_no",
    'encryption_key')::text,
from
    "table_name"
where
    "table_name"."is_active"
order by
    "table_name"."pickup_date_time"
limit 10)
```

To add Pgcrypto in system i follow below steps

- added pgcrypto extension in postgres sql
- added pgcrypto in INSTALLED_APP in base settings.
- added django-pgcrypto-fields plug in.
- replace model char fields to charpgpsymmetric fields.
- copy data in encrypted format in encrypted fields.

Any input will be very helpful, as system is very slow.

expecting query execution time to be minimum

Comment: Decryption isn't cheap. I don't think there is anything you can do, except limit the number of rows.

Comment: Show the output of the EXPLAIN.

Comment: Encryption is security, the cost of security is time. You cannot get the former without spending the latter.